In Latex3, how to test if all tokens in the input verify a test (for example \token_if_letter or \token_if_space)?
In Latex3, I would like to write a function that checks if every token of an input verify a predicate.
Basically I would like the multitoken version of this command:
\NewDocumentCommand{\mychecksingle}{m m m}{
    \bool_if:nTF{\token_if_space_p:N{#1} || \token_if_letter_p:N{#1}}{#2}{#3}
}

which would look like this:
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycheckmulti}{m m m}{
    % Returns #2 if \token_if_space_p:N || \token_if_letter_p is true for every token in the input
    % Returns #3 otherwise
}

How to achieve this with Latex3/expl3?

you can use \tl_map_function:NN to apply a function to every token in a token list

@DavidCarlisle Yes but how to get the global result? I would like code example to see how that works.

You can map over the token list and accumulate the result in several ways, here I generate an integer expression counting how many items fail the predicate then test if that value is 0 at the end
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \vincent_check_one:n #1 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF 
       { \tl_if_single_p:n {#1} }
       { \tl_if_single_token_p:n {#1} }
  {\bool_if:nTF {\token_if_space_p:N #1 || \token_if_letter_p:N #1 } {0+}{1+}}
  {1+}
  }


  \cs_new:Npn \vincent_map_p:nTF #1 {
    \typeout{Debug: \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \vincent_check_one:n   0}
  \int_compare:nTF
  {
    \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \vincent_check_one:n
    0
    =0
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\mycheck{}{\vincent_map_p:nTF} 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mycheck{aa bb ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa b&b ccc}{YES}{NO}


\mycheck{aa {b c}cc}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}



Why not use \tl_map_break:n instead? Also, this might fail horribly if #1 contains braces.

I was going to mention that a more efficient solution would be to break but it depends on the exact overall test whether breaking the loop is possible, clearly it is for an all or none test. I suppose I ought to gurad the groups better, it didn;t fail in the one example tested though:-)  what do we say about token_if... I'll look

They are documented to take N type arguments, so you have to ensure that #1 in \vincent_check_one:n really is valid N type. Also, you can omit testing for spaces since \tl_map_... will silently ignore them (unless { } should pass the test as well).

@Skillmon I test for a group now good call about the  space though

Might still fail on doubly nested groups :) \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n {#1} } { \tl_if_single_token_p:n {#1} } would be better.

@Skillmon done:-)

If we are using only TeX primitives then we have to run \futurelet primitive in a loop. The code is somewhat cumbersome:
\def\mycheck#1{\mycheckA#1\mycheckA}
\def\mycheckA{\futurelet\next\mycheckB}
\def\mycheckB{\ifcat\noexpand\next a\expandafter\mycheckC \else 
              \expandafter\ifx\space\next \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mycheckC \e
              \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mycheckE\fi\fi}
\def\mycheckC{\afterassignment\mycheckA \let\next= }
\def\mycheckE#1\mycheckA{\ifx\next\mycheckA \mycheckT \else \mycheckF \fi}
\def\mycheckT#1\fi#2#3{\fi#2}
\def\mycheckF#1\fi#2#3{\fi#3}

\mycheck{aa bb ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa b&b ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa {b c}cc}{YES}{NO}

\bye

If we are using OpTeX then the \nospacefuturelet instead \futurelet can be used. This macro behaves like \futurelet but there is two more features: it is expandable and it gets first non-space token. So, we needn't check if the inspected token is space:
\def\mycheck#1{\mycheckA:#1\mycheckA}
\def\mycheckA#1{\nospacefuturelet\next\mycheckB}
\def\mycheckB{\ifcat\noexpand\next a\ea\mycheckA \else \ea\mycheckE\fi}
\def\mycheckE#1\mycheckA{\ifx\next\mycheckA \ea\ignoresecond \else \ea\usesecond\fi}

\mycheck{aa bb ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa b&b ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa {b c}cc}{YES}{NO}

\bye

There is another approach: to test the current \catcode for the token which is used currently for tokenization (it doesn't have to be the same as the category of the token which was tokenized sometime earlier). In OpTeX, we can use \foreach macro:
\def\mycheck#1{\ea\foreach\detokenize{#1}\do
   {\ifnum\catcode`##1=11 \else \ea\mycheckF \fi}\ignoresecond
}
\def\mycheckF#1\ignoresecond{\_getforstack\usesecond}

\mycheck{aa bb ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa b&b ccc}{YES}{NO}

\mycheck{aa {b c}cc}{YES}{NO}

\bye

The \_getforstack is here because we leave the \foreach loop immediately when non-letter is found and then we have to close the for-loop stack which OpTeX uses in order to enable \foreach in \foreach.

Since the \tl_map_... functions do not special case groups the following uses etl to loop over your input (which allows to define separate actions for single tokens, spaces, and groups):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \mycheckmulti { m m m }
  {
    \etl_act:nnnnn
      \__vincent_checkmulti_aux:nN % single token needs checking
      \use_none:n % ignore spaces
      { \etl_act_break:n \use_iii:nnn } % nested group means false
      {} % we don't need a status
      {#1}
    \use_i:nn {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_checkmulti_aux:nN #1#2
  { \token_if_letter:NF #2 { \etl_act_break:n \use_iii:nnn } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycheckmulti{is this fine}{yes}{no}
\mycheckmulti{is {t}his fine}{yes}{no}
\mycheckmulti{is this fine?}{yes}{no}
\mycheckmulti{is\space this fine?}{yes}{no}
\end{document}

